# Test @Autowired JpaRepository in spock

Tags: groovy, spock, spring-test

**AccountsRepository**

```
public interface AccountsRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {}
```

**AccountsEndpointTest**

```
class AccountsEndpointTest extends Specification {
  @Shared @Autowired AccountsRepository accountRepository
  @Shared def entriesCount

  def setupSpec() {
     accountRepository = Mock()
  }

  def "create user"() {
    given: "the current number of rows in accounts table"
    entriesCount = accountRepository.count()

    when: "add endpoint is invoked"
    // send /user/add request

    expect: 
    entriesCount < accountRepository.count()

  }
}
```

entriesCount gives me **O** in **given** and **expect** block. I tested this manually and it the return is non-zero since it the table has entries. How to test this properly in spock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spock mocks do not work when they are defined as `@Shared`, but that isn't your problem here. You are missing the `@ContextConfiguration` or `@SpringBootTest` annotation so that spring is actually used and can inject the bean. Also make sure to have the `spock-spring` dependency on the classpath.

As a side note, you can also use

```
expect: 
accountRepository.count() == old(accountRepository.count()) + 1
```

to say that the entry count should have increased.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that instead of interacting with the repository you are interacting with a mock.

In the setupSpec you are replacing the injected repository with a mock which will by default return 0 when interacting with its count method. Remove the setupSpec part to interact with the real injected repository.

Comment: good explanation. however when I try to remove it in the setupSpec blocks, accountRepository becomes null